# nginx 403 Forbidden when render big file

Tags: django, nginx

I build a wee website where i upload some jupyter notebook as html files in order to show some works example.
First notebook i uploaded is less the 1MB size and uploaded and rendered fine, then i tried to upload a bigger file, 4mb, and got a 413 error size to big, after checking online i added to my nginx.conf the line

```
client_max_body_size 10M;
```

and now it upload correctly but still got a nginx 413 error permission denied when render the file.
If i upload a less then 1MB file everything works fine, so my guess is there is still something missing in the conf file in order to enable render of bigger file

my nginx.conf is:

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Server Configs
    ##
#   server {
#       client_max_body_size 10M;
#   }
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

and this is the default

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#

upstream django {
server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name seelv.io www.seelv.io;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
client_max_body_size 10M;
}

server {
listen 443;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /home/seelvio/crt/seelv_io_chain.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /home/seelvio/crt/seelvio.key;
server_name seelv.io;
client_max_body_size 10M;

location /static/ {
alias /home/seelvio/seelvio/seelvio/static/;
try_files $uri =404;

}

location /media/ {
alias /home/seelvio/seelvio/seelvio/media/;
}

location /uploads/ {
alias /home/seelvio/seelvio/seelvio/media/uploads/;
}

location / {
try_files $uri @send_to_django;
}

location @send_to_django {
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_pass http://django;
}
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok i made a step forward, it looks like some files doesn't have enough permissions, if i manually change the permissions in a file adding the read permissions then it render it correct. What i need to understand now is why some files are saved with reading permissions and other do not (seems related with the size of the file)

Comment: HTTP 413 is Payload Too Large (or Request Entity Too Large in Nginx), while 403 is Forbidden. Can you clarify which one you're getting after you increased `client_max_body_size`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this has something to do with [the difference in the way Django, by default, handles uploads of less than 2.5 MB, versus those of larger filesizes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored).

The following is just a guess, but it could be related to the [`FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#file-upload-permissions). As it says on the doc,

> If `None`, you’ll get operating-system dependent behavior. On most platforms, temporary files will have a mode of `0o600`, and files saved from memory will be saved using the system’s standard umask.

So in case you've set it to `None`, you could just try setting it back to the default `0o644`, because this could be what's happening:

- for the uploads of less than 2.5 MB (or whatever you have set [`FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#file-upload-max-memory-size) to), after receiving the file from Nginx, Django holds the data completely in memory before writing it to disk with the system's default permissions, which is likely to be `644`. This allows your Nginx process, which likely runs under a system user such as `www-data`, to read the files that are owned by your user account, assuming you're running Django under your user account.
- for the bigger uploads, Django streams the data to a temporary file first, with `600` permissions, and then moves it to the final storage location while maintaining the permissions. (I'm also guessing this part, the docs don't completely describe Django's behavior on this.) `600` permissions mean that Nginx isn't able to access the file anymore after it has passed the data to Django (again, assuming the likely scenario that Nginx runs under a different account from the one running Django).

Comment: If this doesn't solve your issue, maybe you could share more info on how you're actually handling the file uploads in Django (i.e. what your views look alike), as well as your Django file upload-related settings. About your views, you're using the word "render"—does that mean you're parsing the uploaded HTML file in Python/Django and re-rendering it in the response, instead of letting Nginx serve the uploaded HTML files directly?

Comment: Thanks lot, adding FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644 to settings.py solved the issues.

Comment: @AlessandroSilvestrin good to know! By the way, just a friendly reminder that [you can *accept* helpful answers on this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the friendly reminder, honestly i am still pretty new on stack overflow and didn't know it, so thanks twice